# Why do I get the error message "undefined is not a function" when trying to cancel a promise on press?

Tags: react-native, es6-promise

I have a sleep function that resolves after a timeout and that is awaited for in a async function called go. The function go is called by pressing on a touchableOpacity.

In some cases I want to reject the promise before it resolves by pressing on a touchableOpacity.
For that reason I implemented a function to reject the promise called promiseReject.

Now if a call the go function and then try to cancel the promise by calling promiseReject an error is thrown saying: "undefined is not a function"

I appreciate any help to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance.

```
let promiseReject

const sleep = seconds => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const timeoutId = setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000)

  promiseReject = () => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    reject()
  }
})

const go = async () => {
  await sleep(10)
}

<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    go()
  }}
>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    promiseReject()
  }}
>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `useRef` to store a function to avoid clearing when rendering.

> useRef is a React Hook that lets you reference a value that’s not needed for rendering.

```
const cancel = useRef(null);
...
cancel.current = () => { ... };
...
cancel.current()
```

See [Referencing a value with a ref](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef#referencing-a-value-with-a-ref)  for details.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much. But why is it needed? Where or when does the clearing happen?

Comment: Local variables don’t persist between renders.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is promiseReject is not a function. function is not assigned to promiseRejection.

To avoid that issue just we need to check the promiseReject is funtion or not

```
if(typeof(promiseReject)=="function"){promiseReject()}
```

Updated full code.

```js
let promiseReject: any;

  const sleep = async (seconds: number) => {
    return await new Promise((resolve: any, reject) => {
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
      }, seconds * 1000);

      // console.log('Hello');
      promiseReject = () => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        // console.log('Reject');
        reject();
      };
    });
  };

  const go = async () => {
    console.log('start');

    await sleep(10);
    console.log('end');
  };

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          go();
        }}>
        <Text>GO</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          if (typeof promiseReject == 'function') {
            promiseReject();
          }
        }}>
        <Text>REj</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
```